# is it bad to store different child classes as parent class in java

Tags: java, casting

Is it considered bad practice to store objects as their parent class and compare object.getClass() with an expected class to cast to the sub class.

explanation: as part of a 2D game with tile based movement I have several types of "GameObject" objects like "Portal", "Player", "NPC", "Chest", etc. Each is stored in a 2 dimensional array making up each Level which also acts as an update and rendering queue and the GameObject embodies the information required by the Level.
If I store all objects as the parent type GameObject then cast them to their actual class for example (in Player class):

```
private void checkPosition(x, y) {
    GameObject obj = Level.getObject(x,y);
    if(obj instanceof NPC) {
       NPC npc = (NPC)obj;
       //interact with npc
    } else if(obj instanceof Chest) {
       //handle chest
    }
}
```

Would this generally be harder to read? What problems am I likely to have doing things this way? what would be a better method if any provided each object uses the array to interact with each other and I will likely have other types of "GameObjects" in the future, each with fundamentally different functionality.

sorry if this is wordy as I am not really sure how to explain this question.

edit: I should clarify similar code may be run from other sub classes of GameObject, not just Player (ie NPC or a later Class) and the emphasis is on being able to change the interaction between each sub class without changing the storing Level class each time one of it's potentially stored class type is created/changed. thank you to those who recommended `instanceof` I have updated the question to focus on other parts, but I will likely be using it from now on. Thanks for the feedback.

Conclusion: I have decided to go for a variant of daniu's answer where each GameObject has its own AI subclass which extends a stub/adapter of the mentioned interface. Thus I don't have to implement reactions for ever class, I can give different behaviours to the same object type and handling interaction should look like this:

```
getObject(x,y).getAI().react(obj);
```

Comment: You are correct to have a superclass for all objects in the game. I would use `instanceof` instead of comparing the `getClass` return value, but there's not much else you can do. I would additionally wrap the evaluation in a strategy pattern.

Comment: I edited my answer to provide for several kinds of moving objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a use case for the visitor pattern.

Add an interface (for everything that may move through the level)

```
interface LevelCrawler {
   void accept(Chest chest);
   void accept(NPC npc);
}
```

and to your `GameObject`

```
interface GameObject { // or abstract class
    // added method
    void accept(LevelCrawler lc);  // abstract if class
}
```

The `LevelCrawler` would be implemented by eg the `Player` class (or `NPC` etc as you describe in your edit).

```
class Player implements LevelCrawler {
   public void accept(Chest chest) { ... }
   public void accept(NPC npc) { ... }
}
```

containing the code in the `if () {...}` blocks.

Then, you have eg

```
class Chest implements GameObject {  // I think it's a class, so probably "extends"
    void accept(LevelCrawler p) { p.handle(this); } // to call Player#handle(Chest)
}
```

and your code looks like

```
GameObject o = Level.getObject(x, y);
o.accept(player); // or NPC or whatever is moving right now
```

Look, [it works](https://ideone.com/UrRsxD).

The advantage of this is that when you create a new `GameObject` class, you can easily add the new behavior to the existing `LevelCrawler` classes and leave the `checkPosition` code unchanged.

[Edited version](https://ideone.com/DQaZKu) with both `Player` and `NPC` moving through the dungeon.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using `instanceof` instead of comparing the `class` itself.

```
private void checkPosition(x, y) {
    GameObject obj = Level.getObject(x,y);
    if(obj instanceof NPC) {
       NPC npc = (NPC)obj;
       //interact with npc
    } else if(obj instanceof Chest) {
       //handle chest
    }
}
```

`instanceof` is an operator for testing that an object is of a specified type i.e. `class`, `subclass` or `interface`.

Have a read of the tutorial found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-instanceof) for extra help.

> Before casting an unknown object, the instanceof check should always be used. Doing this helps in avoiding ClassCastException at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
if(obj.getClass() == NPC.class)
```

it would be better to use

```
if (obj instanceof NPC)
```

unless you want to test the exact class without allowing subclasses.

Another option could be to let the objects check their positions on their own and just do

```
private void checkPosition(int x, int y) {
    GameObject obj = Level.getObject(x,y);
    obj.checkPosition()
}
```

or

```
private void checkPosition(int x, int y) {
    GameObject obj = Level.getObject(x,y);
    obj.checkPosition(this)
}
```

depending on what is needed for this position check.